# When should assert() be used?

Tags: c++, assert

In developing a large C++ programming project with many developers, we have run into issues with inappropriate use of assert() in the code which results in poor quality where the assertion does indeed occur and the product crashes.

The question is what are good principles to apply to use assert() appropriately?  When is it proper to use an assert() and when is it not?  Is there a list of criteria that each assertion should pass in order to be legitimate?  How can we encourage proper use of assert()?

As a first crack at this, I would say that assert() should only be used to document a condition that is believed to be impossible to reach and which should be identified as an assert() failure at run time where it ever to arise because programming assumptions are being violated.

Can folks do better than this?  What is your experience with assert()?

Comment: Use assert when you know some condition must prevail in order for the code to be considered "good." If the assert fails, then by definition the code must be fixed.

Comment: @Robert: agreed +1, but there must be consideration given to how much work the user will lose if the assertion firing crashes the program.  It is annoying when a browser loses a set of open tabs, but not usually a disaster; it is a disaster if a word processor loses a day's work because of an assertion.  The hard parts are (a) working out whether it is safe to do anything, and (b) keeping the system in a state where it can be recovered if something goes wrong.

Comment: He who goes a whole day without saving his work gets what he deserves when an assert occurs.

Comment: Asserts should not exist is release code, they should only be used in debug code while the system is being developed. Use Exceptions in release code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use **Exceptions** for error condition which come from the ***outside*** (outside the method or outside the program) like parameter checking and missing/defective external ressources like files or connections or user input.

Use **Assertions** to indicate an ***internal*** defects like programming errors, conditions that shouldn't occur, e.g. class/method invariants and invalid program state.

Answer (score 1):

You should use assert to check all conditions that should never happen:

- Preconditions on input parameters
- Results of intermediate calculations
- Postconditions on object state

But you should include those asserts only in debug builds or when explicitly activated for release (not in builds released to the customers).

Comment: If bad preconditions etc. are from code *completely* under your control than failing an assertion is fine.  But what about situations like these:  missing/wrong dlls, wrong registry entries etc.

Answer (score 1):

I use asserts to check for *any* unwanted program state:

- Function preconditions
- Sometimes I insert them in a macro after every API call: `glDrawArray(); checkOpenGLError();`--`checkOpenGLError()` will call `getGLError()` if turned on
- Data structure integrity: `assert(something == null);`
- Sometimes GDB lies to me (iOS SDK 3.2). I use asserts to prove it.

Note that "unwanted program state" excludes errors that naturally occur at runtime, such as being unable to open a user-selected file due to permissions or HD failure. In these cases it is not wise to use assertions.

Answer (score 0):

Much code nowadays has a lot of external dependencies and connections.  I don't tend to use traditional assertions much these days, I favor exceptions.  I don't feel like I can assume "this can never happen" and the checks can safely be removed in a non-debug build.